# How to change http port number in oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, port

I am trying to use port 8080 for another purpose but the browser prompts for username and password while entering the link for authentication - http://127.0.0.1:8080/login-results.

[image]

I have my oracle database installed in my system and has assigned port 8080 as one of its listening port.

How to change the port number?

Comment: That's the port of the Enterprise Manager, **not** the port of the database.

Comment: Port 8080 was mentioned like this when I checked its status... `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-4TUME6A)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))`

Answer (score 0):

Check the ports used by oracle DB by using the following commands in Command Prompt.

```
> LSNRCTL.EXE
> status
```

> Listening Endpoints Summary...
>     (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
>     (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-4TUME6A)(PORT=1521)))
>     (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-4TUME6A)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))

Then if still, you need to change the HTTP port, open SQL Command-Line and connect to the SQL server by entering the following command.

```
connect system
```

If prompted for a password enter it wait for the **CONNECTED** message. After this enter the following command to change the HTTP port number.

```
exec DBMS_xdb.sethttpport('8081')
```

Check once if the ports are been updated by executing the `LSNRCTL.EXE` & `status` commands.